# Child pages and their featured images are not pulled in the parent page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

For some reason in Genisis framework, wordpress the following code is not pulling up the child pages and its featured images

```
 add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );
function add_body_class( $classes ) {
   $classes[] = 'portfolio';
return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content'         ); // Force Full-Width Layout
remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' ); // Removes     breadcrumbs
remove_action( 'genesis_post_title','genesis_do_post_title' ); // Removes post title
remove_action( 'genesis_post_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' ); // Removes content
add_action( 'genesis_post_content', 'child_do_content' ); // Adds your custom page code/content

     // Do Custom Content
function child_do_content() { ?>

<?php global $wpdb; ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
 <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>

<?php }genesis();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `get_results()` arguments.

First assign `post->ID` to a variable and then use it in `get_results()` like so:

```
$parent = $post->ID;
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = $parent AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
```

Also I am not sure that you can use `menu_order` and `'page'` the way you did, check the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) how to get those.